# Javascript keyword super and class constructors extending PIXI.Graphics

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

Whenever I go to extend the PIXI.Graphics class it gives me an error saying that the keyword "super" is unexpected, with this code

```
class Block extends PIXI.Graphics{
construtor(x=0, y=0, width=50, height=50, color=0xFF0000, border=0, borderColor=0xFFFF00){
    super();
    this.beginFill(color);
    this.lineStyle(border, borderColor, 1);
    this.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
    this.endFill();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    // variables
    this.originX = x;
    this.originY = y;
    this.isAlive = true;
    this.visible = true;
}

die(){
    if (!isAlive){
        this.x = originX;
        this.y = originY;
        this.isAlive = true;
    }
}
```

}

using this.super() instead does not throw an error but this object still does not appear when added to the PIXI app.stage on the page.

Any advice or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: typo at `construtor`, this should be `constructor` in above code.

Comment: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying *and closely inspecting* the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."